# How to upload scan outputs from minIO (ex. Nmap, Nikto, Sslyze, Zap) to OWASP DefectDojo

Tags: devops, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm, owasp

I have problem uploading the findings of minIO securecodebox outputs to OWASP DefectDojo.

Screenshot of Error
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PqVOazjr7r_1oMPf6SQsh8_iPFgnqkjC/view?usp=sharing

I try following these steps
https://github.com/DefectDojo/django-DefectDojo/blob/dev/readme-docs/KUBERNETES.md
then
https://docs.securecodebox.io/docs/hooks/defectdojo/

This is the link for the scanners
https://github.com/secureCodeBox/secureCodeBox/tree/main/scanners

The Error:

2022-03-07 07:23:54 INFO  DefectDojoPersistenceProvider:35 - Downloading Scan Result    ence provider
2022-03-07 07:23:56 INFO  DefectDojoPersistenceProvider:39 - Uploading Findings to DefectDojo at: http://defectdojo.default.minikube.local:8080/                                tDojo at: http://defectdojo.default.minikube.local:8080/
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://defectdojo.default.minikube.locarror on GET request for "http://defectdojo.default.minikube.local:8080/api/v2/users/": defectdojo.default.minikube.local; nested exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: defectdojo.default.minikube.local
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:785)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:751)   rnalSearch(GenericDefectDojoService.java:151)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:621)  ch(GenericDefectDojoService.java:167)
at io.securecodebox.persistence.defectdojo.service.GenericDefectDojoService.intechUnique(GenericDefectDojoService.java:187)rnalSearch(GenericDefectDojoService.java:151)                                           ionedEngagementsStrategy.java:82)
at io.securecodebox.persistence.defectdojo.service.GenericDefectDojoService.search(GenericDefectDojoService.java:167)
at io.securecodebox.persistence.defectdojo.service.GenericDefectDojoService.searchUnique(GenericDefectDojoService.java:187)
at io.securecodebox.persistence.strategies.VersionedEngagementsStrategy.run(VersionedEngagementsStrategy.java:82)
at io.securecodebox.persistence.DefectDojoPersistenceProvider.main(DefectDojoPersistenceProvider.java:42)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: defectdojo.default.minikube.local
at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:229)
at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:558)
at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:182)
at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:474)
at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:569)
at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.(HttpClient.java:242)
at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:341)
at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:362)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1253)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1187)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1081)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:1015)
at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:76)
at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:66)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:776)
... 7 more

Thank you for the reponse!

Comment: My Error:

2022-03-07 07:23:56 INFO  DefectDojoPersistenceProvider:39 - Uploading Findings to DefectDojo at: http://defectdojo.default.minikube.local:8080/                                tDojo at: http://defectdojo.default.minikube.local:8080/
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://defectdojo.default.minikube.locarror on GET request for "http://defectdojo.default.minikube.local:8080/api/v2/users/": defectdojo.default.minikube.local; nested exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: def

Comment: Screenshot of error https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PqVOazjr7r_1oMPf6SQsh8_iPFgnqkjC/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

there is a dedicated DefectDojo Hook which will do it for you.
You just need to install in on a cluster with some basic configuration.

> Installing the DefectDojo persistenceProvider hook will add a ReadAndWrite Hook to your namespace.

> kubectl create secret generic defectdojo-credentials --from-literal="username=admin" --from-literal="apikey=08b7..."

> helm upgrade --install dd secureCodeBox/persistence-defectdojo 
> --set="defectdojo.url=https://defectdojo-django.default.svc"

> The hook will automatically import the scan results into an engagement in DefectDojo. If the engagement doesn't exist the hook will create the engagement (CI/CD engagement) and all objects required for it (product & product type). The hook will then pull the imported information from DefectDojo and use them to replace the findings inside secureCodeBox.

More https://docs.securecodebox.io/docs/hooks/defectdojo